# Story about humans and a humanoid species colonizing the same planet without being aware of each other's presence

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

Two races colonizing the same planet. Each unaware of the other's presence. Each home world is overcrowded and each is similarly advanced. One race is human, the other is humanoid.

Comment: Any more details you can provide? When you might have read it, how old were you at the time, what language was it in, any details of the cover? This is little to go on, so anything else you may remember might be helpful.

Comment: Do you recall this being a book or a short story?

Comment: Does this involve Gungans?

Comment: And we’re assuming it’s a book, you haven’t actually stated that.

Comment: @bitmask - Me'sa hopin' it's not, okey day?

Comment: Agree, this is very vague. Star Trek: Cardassians & Maquis fit this description (loosely).

Answer (score 4):

[*Decision at Doona*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/61957.Decision_at_Doona) (1969) by Anne McCaffrey.  The humans are human :-), the Hrubbans are cat-like humanoids. Both have stagnated civilizations on overcrowded planets and hope to resolve their troubles by going back to nature on so-far unspoiled planets (plus both have a Prime Directive of non-interference after wiping out other species, the eponymous "decision" is that they yet will try for peaceful contact on the new colony world Doona).

Answer (score 2):

*Decision at Doona* is a good answer. Another possibility is [*Planet of no Return*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_and_Answer_(novel)) (aka *Question and Answer*, 1954) by Poul Anderson.

I can't find a plot summary online, but from memory (possible spoilers)

> Humans land on the planet and discover that there is indigenous
>  intelligent life (which would prevent them from colonising). It turns
>  out that the aliens are not indigenous, but colonists as well, just
>  pretending to be indigenous to get control of the planet.

---

> **WANTED:** *terrestroid planets, habitable but uninhabited, clean of major sickness, rich enough to support colonists without outside help*
>
> **FOUND:** *in almost a generation, nothing - Then a shipful of astronomers chanced on the Troas-Ilium system. The Da Gama had set
>   out, but never come home. Now, seven years later, the Henry Hudson is
>   due to leave on the same mission...*

Comment: What about *Planet Of No Return* matches the details in the question?

Comment: @phantom42 - It doesn't seem like a match...

Comment: Here are some more details that seem to fit at least in part:

>>Upon arrival at Troas, ... Eighteen days later, a group of aliens appears. Avery is assigned to learn the aliens' language, and he reports that it is extremely difficult to understand. He is eventually able to determine that the aliens are called the Rorvan, and that they are native to Troas. This is bad news for the expedition, since planets with native intelligent species are off limits to colonization. The Rorvan invite a small group of humans, including Avery and Lorenzen, to accompany them to their settlement.